# Need to call rest webservice in didexitregion of Ibeacon,how is it possible?

Tags: json, rest, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am working on Ibeacon in android, I am calling one web service in didenterRegion with request of UUID of Beacon and one flag for Region enter as true. Same web service I need to call in didexitregion with UUID and flag should be false as user is exiting from that region. In didenterregion,web service is working fine and I am doing accordingly, but in didexitregion, it is not calling what should I do, Please help me.

Comment: Here is my code of onIBeaconServiceConnect()

Comment: getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {MyAsyncTask obj = new MyAsyncTaskForDataBeacon();obj.execute(getString(R.string.sendDataToServer),region.getProximityUuid(),"false"); }}}); try {
   iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("8aefb031-6c32-486f-825b-e26fa193487d",     "8aefb031-6c32-486f-825b-e26fa193487d", null, null));} catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}

Comment: Is your didExitRegion method even getting called?  You should add a log statement inside of this to make sure.

Comment: yes I have generated simple notification that is coming.. But not frequently.. its coming sometime. That's why I called web service.. I have logged now but it is not calling, can you please suggest what to do now?? please

Comment: can any one help me how to call didexitregion()?? please suggest